# justify-content:space-between not work, Nextjs application

Tags: html, css, reactjs, flexbox, next.js

I have two divs inside a container in my Next.js app, `justify-content: space-between;` doesn't work, but `justify-content: center;` works fine. When I copy and paste the same code on an `index.html` file it works properly.

```
export default function Home() {
  return(
    <div className={styles.container}>
      <div>1</div>
      <div>2</div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

**css file**

```
.container {
  padding: 2rem 2rem;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
.container div {
  color: red;
  font-size: 35px;
}
```

Comment: You seem to be missing a closing div tag. Please post rendered HTML for CSS questions.

Comment: no value set to `justify-content` will matter since your flex doesn't have any width set.

Answer (score 1):

Without setting the width of your div, justify-content: space-between doesn't work.Set the div width first just like below.

```
.container {
  padding: 2rem 2rem;
  display: flex;
   width: //whatever width you want
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

i think "className" is wrong and "class" is correct.

```
<div class="container">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
</div>
```

**css code:**

```
.container {
   padding: 2rem 2rem;
   display: flex;
   justify-content: space-between;
}
.container div {
  color: red;
  font-size: 35px;
}
```

Comment: As the author stated that the react framework is used, className is the correct way of setting a css class to an element.